# Perform calculation on each row of a single column from data frame

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame (`data`):

```
  sample chrom     pos ref alt tri trans decomposed_tri grouped_trans    type    feature       gene
1 1    1  659105   G   A CGT   G>A            ACG           C>T somatic     intron         ds
2 1    1 1227592   A   G CAC   A>G            GTG           T>C somatic     intron    CG42329
3 1    1 1775341   T   G CTG   T>G            CTG           T>G somatic intergenic intergenic
4 1    1 1775552   T   C GTT   T>C            GTT           T>C somatic intergenic intergenic
5 1    1 1812639   T   G GTG   T>G            GTG           T>G somatic intergenic intergenic
6 1    1 1812641   G   A GGA   G>A            TCC           C>T somatic intergenic intergenic
```

And a list of genes with their lengths (`gene_lengths`):

```
$`128up`
[1] 1553

$`14-3-3epsilon`
[1] 8019

$`14-3-3zeta`
[1] 10010

$`140up`
[1] 1385

$`18SrRNA-Psi:CR41602`
[1] 1974

$`18SrRNA-Psi:CR45861`
[1] 1933
```

And I want to:
**a)** Calculate the number of times you would expect to see a gene in this list given the length of the gene (in `gene_lengths`) and the length of the genome (`137547960`)
**b)** Calculate the number of times we actually see each gene  `hit_genes<-table(data$gene)`
**c)** Calculate the a ratio of observed/expected `fc<-gene_lengths[g]/gene_expect`
**d)** Return this as a data frame

Here's what I'm doing:

```
snv_count<-nrow(data) # total number of observations
hit_genes<-table(data$gene) # the number of times I find each gene in my data
cat("gene", "observed", "expected", "fc", "\n")

for (g in levels(data$gene)) {
    genefraction<-gene_lengths[[g]]/137547960
    gene_expect<-snv_count*(genefraction)
    fc<-gene_lengths[g]/gene_expect
    cat(g, hit_genes[g], gene_expect, fc, "\n")
  }
```

---

```
gene observed expected fc
128up 5 1.493344 3.348189 
18SrRNA-Psi:CR45861 3 0.5076489 5.909596 
C442219 4 0.03778505 105.862
```

This works. However, I'm running this in a function, and want to return a data frame, how can I build a data frame row by row in the for loop? I've tried initialising an empty data frame before the loop:

```
df <- data.frame(gene = character(), observed = numeric(), expected = numeric(), fc = numeric())
```

and then building row by row in the loop:

```
enriched <- rbind(df, data.frame(gene = g, observed = hit_genes[g], expected = gene_expect, fc = fc))
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(gene = g, observed = hit_genes[g], expected = gene_expect,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

A further question is - should I be using `ddply` to achieve this rather than a loop?

Comment: can you supply us with some example data using `dput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with `?lapply`. (Untested.)

```
enriched <- lapply(levels(data$gene), fun)
enriched <- do.call(rbind, enriched)
enriched

# 'fun' returns a list with four members
fun <- function(g) {
    genefraction<-gene_lengths[[g]]/137547960
    gene_expect<-snv_count*(genefraction)
    fc<-hit_genes[g]/gene_expect
    list(gene = g, observed = hit_genes[g], expected = gene_expect, fc = fc)
}
```

Note that this assumes that the objects referred to in functions `fun` is available, i.e., in the global environment.

Comment: This is great - how can I output multiple columns? When I run this I only get the fc column as output.

Comment: You can have the function `fun` return whatever you want, but if you return multiple columns the `do.call` trick might not work. To construct `enriched` you might need something else. What exactly depends on the function's return object. I will edit my answer to give you a hint on what `fun` can return.